# Asp.net Grid view Fill Bulk Data in background

Tags: asp.net

We Have a Bulk Data bind To Grid and The Datasource Like Datatable Store in Cache. I Want that When i Click The Button It Fill only Top 100 Record in Grid and Reset are Fill in Background.

Actaully when i Fill Whole Record in one time then it hange the screen and display white Background. i am not want to use paging in grid view according to client.

So it thier any way for fill grid view in Background So that in first time it fill 100 recods an in backgroud fill record automatically

Comment: What is the used data source ?

Comment: Oracle is Database and oledb Datasource